# Multiple else if not working correctly PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm having an issue with a login script. The rest of it works fine, but there is something odd happening here. The issue is that even though $IPCHK is returning true the elseif function does not execute. It only executes when I set $IPCHK to jibberish. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

```
if ($Numrows == 0)
{
    if ($Fail >= 3)
    {
        $Connection = connectToDb();
        //return true, false,pending
        $IPCHK = checkIP();
        $IPCHK = true; //forcing it to be true and still broke
        //If no ip id there
        if($IPCHK == false)
        {
            $IP = getIP();
            $Query = "INSERT INTO ip VALUES ('','$IP',Now())";
            mysqli_query($Connection, $Query)
                or die(error(mysqli_error($Connection)));
            echo "You have failed to login too many times";
            echo "<br />Please <a href='login.php'>try again</a> later.";
            $Lock = true;
        }
        //If ip is there but timer is not up
        elseif ($IPCHK == 'pending')
        {
            echo "You have failed to login too many times";
            echo "<br />Please <a href='login.php'>try again</a> later.";
            $Lock = true;
        }
        //Timers Up
        elseif ($IPCHK == true) //here does not execute when it returns true
        {
            $_SESSION['FailedLogin'] = 0;
            $Lock = false;
        }
        else
        {
            error("End of if check");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $Fail = 3 - $Fail;
        $_SESSION['FailedLogin'] = $_SESSION['FailedLogin'] + 1;
        $Error = $Error."<br />You have ".$Fail." attempts remaining";
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use a SWITCH statement?

Comment: I'm guessing you have an error one of these two: `$Connection = connectToDb();` `$IPCHK = checkIP();` ? Comment those lines and try again

Comment: I would find a way to `var_dump()` the output to make sure your not getting anything weird.

Comment: == is equality in PHP, === is identity. Any non-empty string coerces to "true", so `$IPCHK == 'pending'` when $IPCHK is "true" will evaluate as true and kick in. Use === to rule out mixed type conditional craziness.

Comment: Thanks ADRock that worked great :D
And thankyou everyone else for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Condition you have

```
 elseif ($IPCHK == 'pending')
```

then

```
elseif ($IPCHK == true)
```

the second else will never execute because $IPCHK == 'pending' means also that $IPCHK == true
if you want to execute your second else you have to change the seconde condition to somethig like this

```
elseif($IPCHK == 'done')
```

or simply use === like this

```
elseif($IPCHK === 'pending')
```

then

```
elseif($IPCHK === true)
```

Comment: He could also use `===` to force a type match - `$IPCHK === 'pending'` would be false if $IPCHK was a boolean true.

Comment: seconded. Don't mix == and ===, always use === unless you have a really good reason to rely on implicit type conversion

Answer (score 0):

Lamari Alaa is correct, and the relevant documentation entry on [type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) can help understand why.

The following script outputs: `boolean = string`:

```
$test = true;

if( $test == 'pending' ) {
    echo 'boolean = string';
} else if ( $test ) {
   echo 'boolean != string';
}
```

This is because the string 'pending' is being coerced into a boolean value before being compared to the boolean value true.  Since it evaluates as true, the first condition is taken.  Consider replacing `== 'pending'` to `=== 'pending'`